# LESS mixin apply to nested DIV

Tags: html, css, less

I have a nested `div` structure like this:

```
<div class="Button" id="StartButton" >
    <div class="buttonIcon" id="startButtonIcon"></div>
    <div class="buttonText" id="startButtonText">Start</div>
</div>
```

and a couple LESS mixins I use to format the parent `div` as a button shape, the icon as an actual image, and the text as special formatting like this:

```
.button-base() {
     ... LESS code here
}

.buttonIcon(@image) {
    ... LESS code
}

.buttonText() {
   ... LESS code
}
```

and here's my LESS structuring for the HTML:

```
#startButton {
    .button-base();

    #startButtonIcon {
            .buttonIcon('img/icon_start_default.png', 'img/icon_start_hover.png');
            }

    #startButtonText {
            .buttonText;
            }
   }
```

What I'd like to do is apply the `hover` selector in the `.button-base()` LESS mixin and have it change the image and text of the nested DIVs appropriately. I can't seem to figure out the right way to use the `&` selector in the parent Mixin.

I'm also open to restructuring the DIV group so that i can control the Icon & text from just 1 LESS mixin. I'm not sure how I would do that though, since i'm also such a beginner at HTML, LESS/CSS etc.

Any help is appreciated!

BTW, here's a jsFiddle that shows what I'm trying to accomplish. I know you can hard code the CSS, but I'm trying to avoid that and use best practices and automate as much as possible with the LESS code: http://jsfiddle.net/tLfqzq8c/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you loking for:

```
.Button {
    width: 115px;
    height: 30px;
    border-color: #ececec;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666666;
    background: #ececec url('http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/6.3/main/89ff52cc-8b6d-4a8e-bae3-5bfca40dcb59_18.png') no-repeat 10%;
}
.Button:hover {
    color: white;
    background-image: url('http://www.phiadariasoft.com/main/images/windows_icon.png');
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="Button" id="StartButton" >
    Start
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured the answer might be to just restructure the HTML DIV elements. I was hoping to avoid that since the page I'm redesigning already has that structure with a lot of buttons in place, but if it means better streamlined LESS code than I'm ok with that. Thanks for the help!